# How to make sure the correct column order while doing spark dataframe.write().insertInto("table")?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using the following code to insert a dataframe data directly into a databricks delta table:

```
eventDataFrame.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("inferSchema","true").insertInto("some delta table"))
```

but if the column order with which the detla table created is different than the dataframe column order, the values get jumbled up and then don't get written to the correct columns. How to maintain the order? Is there a standard way/best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2):

this is fairly simple -

`

```
####in pyspark 

df= spark.read.table("TARGET_TABLE")  ### table in which  we need to insert finally 

df_increment ## the data frame which has random column order which we want to insert into TARGET_TABLE
df_increment =df_increment.select(df.columns)
df_increment.write.insertInto("TARGET_TABLE")
```

`

so for you it will

```
parent_df=   spark.read.table("some delta table") 
eventDataFrame.select(parent_df.columns).write.format("delta").mode("append").option("inferSchema","true").insertInto("some delta table"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use saveAsTable column order doesn't matter with it, spark would find the correct column position by column name.

`eventDataFrame.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("inferSchema","true").saveAsTable("foo")`

From spark documentation.

> The column order in the schema of the DataFrame doesn't need to be same as that of the existing table. Unlike insertInto, saveAsTable will use the column names to find the correct column positions